# Complexity of this variant of the Monotone(+,2−) -SAT problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, satisfiability

In this [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16634/157195),Monotone$(+, 2^-)$-SAT problem is defined as follows:

Given a monotone CNF formula $F^+$, where each variable appears exactly once (as a positive literal), and a monotone 2-CNF formula $F_2^-$ defined on the same variables as $F^+$, where all variables are negated. Is $F^+ \land F_2^-$ satisfiable ?), let us define the Monotone$(+, 2^-)$-SAT problem:

Given a monotone CNF formula $F^+$, where each variable appears exactly once (as a positive literal), and a monotone 2-CNF formula $F_2^-$ defined on the same variables as $F^+$, where all variables are negated. Is $F^+ \land F_2^-$ satisfiable ?

Consider this variant of Monotone(+,2−)-SAT problem where we restrict the number of clause of $F^+$ to be 2 and the width of these 2 clause can be anything ,that means that every instance of positive literal appears in only 2 clause.

Is this variant also NP-complete? I don't see any direct reduction from the main problem to this variant ,so does there exist any reduction or is it solvable in polynomial time?

Comment: Some text in the post appears to be duplicated (2nd and 3rd paragraph).  Perhaps you might like to [edit] your post?

Comment: Yes ,its from the post mentioned above.

Comment: what specific edits do i need to make?

Answer (score 1):

It is in P.  Suppose the first clause of $F^+$ has $k_1$ variables, and the second clause has $k_2$ variables.  Then there are $k_1 k_2$ ways to pick one variable from the first clause, and one variable from the second clause.  For each such way, set those variables to true in $F_2^-$ (i.e., replace those variables with true, and simplify).  The result is a 2-CNF formula, and you can test satisfiability of it in linear time.  Check whether the result is satisfiable.  If it is, then you obtain a satisfying assignment for $F^+ \land F_2^-$.  Repeat once for each of these $k_1 k_2$ possibilities.