# Complexity of deciding the satisfiability of quasi-monotone 3-SAT?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

This question:[Complexity of deciding the satisfiability of a quasi-monotone CNF formula](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16483)
asked whether quasi-monotone SAT is NP-complete or not ?

I want to know if the restricted version of this SAT that is quasi-monotone 3-SAT is NP-complete or not, in this restricted quasi-monotone 3-SAT each clause has exactly 3 literal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question you linked already shows how to transform a quasi-monotone 3-SAT formula into a quasi-monotone formula in which each clause has either $2$ or $3$ literals.

To get a formula in which each clause has exactly 3 literals, we just need to "pad" each clause with $2$ literals while preserving quasi-monotonicity property.

To do so, we repeat the following procedure for each clause $(\ell_1 \vee \ell_2)$ with $2$ literals:

- Introduce the new variables $a,b,c,d,x,y,z$
- Add the clauses $(\overline{a} \vee \overline{b} \vee \overline{x}) \wedge (\overline{a} \vee \overline{b} \vee x)$. This forces at least one of $a$ and $b$ to be set to false.
- Add the clauses $(\overline{a} \vee \overline{c} \vee \overline{y}) \wedge (\overline{a} \vee \overline{c} \vee y)$. This forces at least one of $a$ and $c$ to be set to false.
- Add the clauses $(\overline{a} \vee \overline{d} \vee \overline{z}) \wedge (\overline{a} \vee \overline{d} \vee z)$. This forces at least one of $a$ and $d$ to be set to false.
- Add the clause $(b, c, d)$. This forces at least one of $b,c,d$ to be set to true, which implies that $a$ must be set to false.
- Replace  $(\ell_1 \vee \ell_2)$ with the equivalent clause $(\ell_1 \vee \ell_2 \vee a)$.

Therefore the quasi-monotone 3-SAT problem (with *exactly* 3 literal per clause) is also NP-complete.

Comment: Thanks , Steven.